# W3C HTML5 validator error: An body start tag seen but an element of the same type was already open

Tags: html, validation, w3c

I post this question because I'm having some errors with the w3c validator in my page ([Link to validation](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://infoserver29200.gaming.multiplay.co.uk/tumae/&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=HTML5&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator/1.3%20http://validator.w3.org/services)).

It outputs me a lot of strange errors related with my HTML 5 markup, being this the main error I can't get out of my head:

> Line 15, Column 6: An body start tag seen but an element of the same type was already open

I have looked a lot into this problem and I'm not able to find any solutions.

Although there are more strange errors, such as

> Line 14, Column 7: Stray end tag head

I'm specially interested in the first exposed one, which I would like you to help me solving this.

Thanks in advance!

**Problem solved:**
*Conclusions*:

1. Never display data into the `<head>` tag, otherwise, a body tag will be automatically opened.
2. The `<noscript>` tag content is considered by the validator as displayable, so It's convenient to take care of what we write into the tag.

Comment: The validator is telling you that your page structure is wrong. You haven't posted any code here, so there's nothing more to say.

Comment: Thanks for answering! This has been my first question, I didn't know I had to put the code here. I'm really sorry for that, hope It won't happen again!. Thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `noscript` element in the `head` element contains text output. This is not allowed in the `head` element; `noscript` in the `head` element may contain only `link`, `style`, and `meta` elements ([see the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-noscript-element)). Any displayable content implicitly closes the `head` element and opens the `body` element (because of their content models and the fact that [both opening and closing tags for them are optional](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#optional-tags)).

Comment: Thanks! That solved my problem, now I have put the `<noscript>` tag in the body. I have only one more problem which is related with the `<meta>` tag for disabling page cache: Bad value expires for attribute http-equiv on element meta. And this is my meta tag: <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">. I would appreciate a lot that you help me with this, anyway, you have already helped a lot! Thanks for your answer!.

Comment: The [actual spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#attr-meta-http-equiv) defines only 3 conforming (i.e. valid) values for this attribute, not including `expires`. I don't consider this validation error a big issue, however, it's [not a very good idea](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1341116/2533215) to count on meta elements to prevent caching. It's better to set up the server for sending real HTTP headings needed for that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but, If I don't have access to those server configs, how can I do this with HTML?, I have read something about cache manifest ( [Link here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/) ). Am I in the good way?.